# How to write jUnit tests for private methods

Tags: unit-testing, methods, junit, private

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best way of unit testing private methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/whats-the-best-way-of-unit-testing-private-methods)

As private method's visibility does not allow for them to be seen outside of the class, how can you write tests to make sure they work as expected?

Suppose making them protected or public is not an option. Additionally suppose that your test code must reside separately from your production code.

Please advise and if possible, provide an example

Comment: More specifically, a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/whats-the-proper-way-to-test-a-class-with-private-methods-using-junit